# Human-like summarization of collection of texts

Tags: open-source, language, nlp

Wondering if there is any tool, preferably open-source, that generates a  human-like summary of a corpus of articles/tweets/books?

Assuming one has lots of article abstracts, I would like to make a one-paragraph summary of all the main points.

Comment: Not come across an open source one. Check out something like http://autotldr.io/ There was also an app called Summly which Yahoo bought and then discontinued.

Answer (score 2):

It is not open source, but OpenAI has a "2nd grader summary"(https://beta.openai.com/examples/default-summarize) and a "tldr-summary" API for this: https://beta.openai.com/examples/default-tldr-summary, and there is a free tier.

A few weeks ago I gave it the first few paragraphs of Immanuel Kant's "Critique of Pure Reason" (or the Wikipedia about it, I don't remember) to summarize. The GPT-3 model could not do this properly, but it responded with a human-like "Listen, pal, such texts are difficult to summarize even for a machine like me..."

Comment: Thank you @knb. Do you know if they allow the summarization of more than 1 article?

Comment: THere is one `"prompt":` argument  in the API call where your text is supposed to be put. So no I don't think so. I think it is best to submit 1 article per API-request.  You can do so relatively easily in a loop say in a shell script or in a python script. -- People have started about "Prompt engineering", putting the text there in just the right order to get good results: https://twitter.com/amli_art/status/1549555691181854720 (in this example, for descriptions of AI-generated pixel grahics)

Answer (score 2):

One may use the Python library [GPT Index](https://github.com/jerryjliu/gpt_index) (MIT license but relies on GPT-3, which is closed-source + non-free) to summarize a collection of documents. From the [documentation](https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/use_cases.html#use-case-summarization-over-documents):

> ```
> index = GPTTreeIndex(documents)
> response = index.query("<summarization_query>", mode="summarize")
> ```
>
> The “default” mode for a tree-based query is traversing from the top of the graph down to leaf nodes. For summarization purposes we will want to use `mode="summarize"`.
>
> A summarization query could look like one of the following:
>
> - “What is a summary of this collection of text?”
> - “Give me a summary of person X’s experience with the company.”

FYI {1} is a great paper looking at GPT-3 performance for summarization, but they only looked at short texts, not collections of texts.

---

References:

- {1} Goyal, Tanya, Junyi Jessy Li, and Greg Durrett. "[News Summarization and Evaluation in the Era of GPT-3.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.12356.pdf)" arXiv preprint arXiv:2209.12356 (2022).

Answer (score 0):

One may use the Python library https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain (MIT license) to summarize a collection of documents.

From the [documentation](https://langchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases/summarization.html):

```
from langchain.chains.summarize import load_summarize_chain
chain = load_summarize_chain(llm, chain_type="map_reduce")
chain.run(docs)
```